# in codeigniter how do i do a join with a where clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, where-clause

so i have two tables, and i want to get all the rows from table 1 that meet the where clause conditions, and then join them with table two based on the join conditions.

here are the sample tables:

```
table1:

col1   col2  col3
1      a     val1
2      b     val2
3      c     val3

table2:

col1   col3
1      someval1
2      someval2
3      someval3
```

now i want to grab all the rows in table 1 where col1 = 2, and join those rows with rows from table2 where table2.col1 = table1.col1.  Does that make sense?

Comment: roytuts.com/codeigniter-join-example/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's been a while since I wrote CI, but as per [this docs page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select), your solution might look like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.col1 = table2.col1');
$this->db->where('table1.col1', 2);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

*note* this answer is in no way to be construed as an endorsement of working with Code Igniter ;-)

Comment: ya i was thinking of that too, except i wasnn't sure if where clause will be applied to table 1 instead of the join of table1 and table 2.

Comment: That has more to do with how your DB driver compiles it's queries; but in almost all cases, the where clause will be applied first, so that the query only performs the join on the one row which matches the where clause.

Comment: In other words, it will notice that it can avoid work by applying the where clause to the rows in table1 first, and *then* doing the join. This is what we refer to as *building the query execution plan*. In most cases, ON and WHERE clauses are handled similarly; and usually it's done in a very efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$this->db->select('*'); // Select field
$this->db->from('table1'); // from Table1
$this->db->join('table2','table1.col1 = table2.col1','INNER'); // Join table1 with table2 based on the foreign key
$this->db->where('table1.col1',2); // Set Filter
$res = $this->db->get();
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('book_id, book_name, author_name, category_name');
$this->db->from('books');
$this->db->join('category', 'category.category_id = books.category_id');
$this->db->where('category_name', 'Self Development');
$query = $this->db->get();

// Produces SQL:
 select book_id, book_name, author_name, category_name from books 
 join category on category.category_id = books.category_id 
 where category_name = "Self Development"
```